# ¿Existe un catálogo con todos los libros (en sus distintas ediciones) publicados en Español?

Tags: recursos

Estoy buscando todas las ediciones de un libro en particular. Para eso, sería ideal encontrar un catálogo online (por ejemplo, de una universidad, biblioteca pública, academia de lengua) que contenga dicha información.

De momento no he encontrado un recurso de esa naturaleza, ni nada que se le acerque. Por ejemplo, el libro que quiero (uno de millones de ventas en el mundo) no está disponible en la [biblioteca](http://www.rae.es/biblioteca-y-archivo/biblioteca/acceso-los-catalogos) de la RAE. Es más, solo tiene un libro de este autor, muy prolífico.

La RAE parece tener *corpora* y bases de datos (e.g. [acá](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/crea) y [acá](http://www.asale.org/obras-y-proyectos/corpes-xxi)), pero no parece corresponder a un catálogo universal de libros.

¿Existe un catálogo de esta naturaleza para el Español? ¿O algo que se le parezca? Por ejemplo, ¿el catálogo de libros más extendido de todos en el mundo hispanohablante?

PD: nótese que el ejemplo de un libro en particular sólo desea motivar la pregunta. No quiero ssaber cómo encontrar todas las ediciones para ese libro en particular (por eso prefiero no mencionar detalles sobre este).

Answer (score 2):

Una buena opción parece ser [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/), que se define a sí misma como:

> WorldCat is the world's largest network of library content and services. WorldCat libraries are dedicated to providing access to their resources on the Web, where most people start their search for information.

He hecho un par de búsquedas de libros en Español y me entrega muy buenos resultados. Parece ser un recurso que sólo va a crecer, en la medida que más y más unviersidades y bibliotecas se unan a su servicio.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes también el recurso de las agencias nacionales del ISBN, donde están catalogadas todas las ediciones a las que se adjudican un ISBN. El problema es que, hasta donde alcanzo a saber, sólo están disponibles a nivel nacional, por separado.

Aquí tienes, por ejemplo, la española: [Agencia Española del ISBN](http://www.mcu.es/webISBN/tituloSimpleFilter.do?cache=init&prev_layout=busquedaisbn&layout=busquedaisbn&language=es)